# How to visualize 3D contingency matrix?

Tags: data-visualization, contingency-tables

I have a data like this:

```
> table(A,B,C)
, , C = FALSE

       B
A       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE   177   42
  TRUE      6    8

, , C = TRUE

       B
A       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     5   31
  TRUE      4   10
```

How can I plot this on a single graph, possibly without imposing any hierarchy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would try some kind of 3D heatmap, [mosaic plot](http://www.datavis.ca/papers/drew/) or a [sieve plot](http://www.improving-visualisation.org/visuals/tag=:sieve+plot/mode=1/sort=alpha) (available in the [vcd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/index.html) package). Isn't the base `mosaicplot()` function working with three-way table? (at least `mosaic3d()` in the [vcdExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcdExtra/index.html) package should work, see e.g. http://datavis.ca/R/)

Here's an example (including a conditional plot):

```
A <- sample(c(T,F), 100, replace=T)
B <- sample(c(T,F), 100, replace=T)
C <- sample(c(T,F), 100, replace=T)
tab <- table(A,B,C)
library(vcd)
sieve(tab, shade=TRUE)
cotabplot(tab)
library(vcdExtra)
mosaic3d(tab, type="expected", box=TRUE)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Actually, the rendering of `mosaic3d()` rely on the [rgl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) package, so it is hard to give a pretty picture of the result.

Comment: +1 this is neat, I'd forgotten about the vcdExtra package.

Answer (score 11):

I recently came across a paper by Hadley Wickham and I was reminded of this question (I must spend too much time on the site!)

> Wickham, Hadley and Heike Hofmann. 2011. [Product
>   plots](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TVCG.2011.227). *IEEE Transactions on
>   Visualization and Computer Graphics (Proc. Infovis `11)*. [Pre-print
>   PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/prodplots.pdf)
>
> Abstract
>
> We propose a new framework for visualising tables of counts,
>   proportions and probabilities. We call our framework product plots,
>   alluding to the computation of area as a product of height and width,
>   and the statistical concept of generating a joint distribution from
>   the product of conditional and marginal distributions. The framework,
>   with extensions, is sufﬁcient to encompass over 20 visualisations
>   previously described in ﬁelds of statistical graphics and infovis,
>   including bar charts, mosaic plots, treemaps, equal area plots and
>   ﬂuctuation diagrams.

I know it is typical to try to give greater explanation, but I don't think I can do any better job than the abstract and posting some pictures! The novel examples they present in the right most images (I believe) meet your requirements without imposing a hierarchy.

[image]