# How to visualize both total counts of categories and proportions of subcategories in a plot?

Tags: r, categorical-data, data-visualization, ggplot2, many-categories

Suppose I have samples drawn from categories A, B, C. Within those categories, I have subcategories d,e,f which are found in all 3 categories. I want to visualize how many samples I have form categories A, B, C *and* the proportional composition of subcategories d,e,f within each category.

One way to do this is a bar plot (I'm using ggplot2, not  that it matters too much) with bars for A, B, C, heights proportional to their total number of samples. Within each bar I partition it by fill color based on the composition of d,e,f within the category. The problem with this is that since A, B, and C will be different heights, it's almost impossible to visually compare the proportions - e.g. proportion of d in A with the proportion of d in B.

To see the proportions, I can renormalize the heights to 100% instead of the sample count so that bars for A, B, and C are now equal height. However, now I can't visualize the counts in A, B, and C.

Is there an elegant way to visualize both of these piece of information simultaneously?

Comment: Hadley Wickham's product plots seems to a fruitful approach to what you are suggesting, see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20900/1036) with an example and further reference.

Comment: Thanks @Andy W ... a spine plot is actually perfect for this since the subcategories are the same across categories (I also tried mosaic plots, but a spine plot is better for comparisons). Using the horizontal width for the category counts seems so obvious in retrospect. Now if only I could do this in ggplot2 without those messy horizontal and vertical stacking calculations (there's a spineplot function in the base package, but it looks pretty ugly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example of embedded/layered bar plots may represent one alternative.  The three main categories are represented by individual bars, then embedded within are subcategory bars (created in ggplot2).

[Blog Link (Learning R)](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/ggplot2-marimekko-replacement-overlapping-bars/)