# Binned continuous X axis and stacked probability bars on Y axis - does this plot have a name?

Tags: probability, categorical-data, data-visualization, continuous-data

After reading a question about binned continuous X axis and stacked probability bars on Y axis I am wondering whether this plot has a name. Here is an example:

[image: What name?]

What this plot shows: We see how the proportions of the categories Yes, Maybe and No change depending on the binned Predictor value. Here, I used random data, so not much interesting is going on, i.e. there is no clear trend in the plot. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70094952/11538509) about plot and data generation.

Comment: It's a stacked bar chart.  Could you indicate how having a name might help you solve a statistical problem?  For research into visualization methods, perhaps?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I write my dissertation about data visualization and can't find a reference. Hard to find without knowing how to name it. I read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38350/alternative-to-sieve-mosaic-plots-for-contingency-tables) similar question by gung and was hoping someone can help me, too. A stacked bar chart is quite broad in my opinion. If there is no exact name I will call it something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no more specific name for a stacked bar chart with a binned continuous X-axis and probability on the Y-axis.